# How to call TestNG Reporter.log on timeOut?

Tags: java, timeout, testng

How to log the timeout in TestNG Reporter.log when timeOut happens. @Test(timeOut=someUnitOfTime)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the [IInvokedMethodListener.afterInvocation](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html#afterInvocation(org.testng.IInvokedMethod,%20org.testng.ITestResult)) method.

```
if(arg1.getThrowable() instanceof org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException){
                Reporter.log("Timeout it is!");
            }
```